# Не удаётся повторно установить Visual Studio из-за того, что диск на котором он раньше был установлен сломался

Tags: visual-studio, установка

Ранее установил Visual Studio и успешно пользовался, однако со временем жёсткий диск на котором он был установлен вышел из строя, после повторной установки, VS проработал ещё пару дней, после чего были проблемы с stdio.h и stdlib.h. На форуме прочитал ответ про переустановку компилятора, однако не знал как это сделать и решил переустановить всю IDE. Удалил, а теперь при установке столкнулся с невозможностью сделать это. Выдаёт ошибку: "Не удаётся получит доступ к диску G". Во вкладке "Расположение установки" единственное, что на нём располагается это - Общие компоненты, инструменты и пакеты SDK. Однако строка для выбора пути серая и я никак не могу изменить этот путь.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Диска G в системе нет вообще, только C, D, E.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Местоположение установки «Общие компоненты, инструменты и пакеты SDK» можно задать только один раз, при первой установке Visual Studio.

Запись об этом сохраняется в реестре и при последующих установках происходит проверка на наличие записи в реестре.

Если вы удалили VS и хотите переустановить и сбросить местоположение установки, вы можете удалить разделы реестра, которые были созданы при первой установке, а затем снова открыть VS Installer, чтобы графа выбора пути установки была доступна:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\ VisualStudio\Setup\SharedInstallationPath
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup\SharedInstallationPath

Comment: Изучил переменные path, и там не было ни одного пути явно указывающего на диск G.
А в управлении дисками тоже не нашёл ничего с ним связанного, только 2 накопителя и системный диск С зарезервированными разделами.

Comment: @Agrresor действительно, переменные добавляются не в PATH, а в реестр. Исправил ответ - должно помочь. Если поможет - пометьте ответ решением. В противном случае - пишите.